# OAuth - How is it secure?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am writing some code to get Twitter and Instagram feed. Before I can write any code, I keep wanting to get a good understanding of oAuth because I have this nagging feeling that it is not all that secure and that most times, for instance when accessing public tweets, it is an unnecessary hassel. I started reading the [oAuth 2 specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-12#section-2) to get a better understanding, I am still in the middle of it. And I have a host of questions.

Let's use Twitter as an example.
A user accesses your site. You redirect them to Twitter for authentication and to obtain the authorization_grant code.
I understand this part is secure because the user authentication and the redirect to your website will happen over ssl. Is it enough for Twitter to support SSL or does your site also have to support SSL for the redirect to be secure? You wouldn't want the authorization code to be transferred insecurely, right?

Now that you have your authorization_grant code, your site will send a request to Twitter to obtain an access token. When making this request your site will send the authorization_grant code, your client id and client secret. Again I guess the communication is secure because this will happen over ssl. But what if the site has included the client id and secret somewhere in its HTML or Javascript, especially if it is a static site with no server side code?
Should the redirect url always be handled by server side code and the server side code should make the request for access token without ever going through HTML or Javascript?

Once you have the access token, you will include it in your request to obtain the user's tweets, to post tweets on their behalf etc. Again if the site in question were to include the access token inside its HTML or JavaScript along with the client id and secret, that would be pretty insecure, right?

It seems all the security of oAuth stems from ssl and the client's ability to keep their client secret secret. Am I right in this conclusion?

Another thing - in the first step of the process, when the client redirects the user to Twitter to authenticate and obtain the authorization_grant code, they could send in their client id and secret and get the access token directly instead of making a second request for it. I think this is what they mean by the implicit method in the specification.
So, why was this extra step of sending a second request to obtain access token added in the specification? Does it increase security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about twitter API, I am talking with respect to stackexchange API
https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication

> Again I guess the communication is secure because this will happen
>   over ssl. But what if the site has included the client id and secret
>   somewhere in its HTML or Javascript, especially if it is a static site
>   with no server side code?

**client_secret** is send only in the case of explicit flow. Explicit flow should be used by server side application and care should be taken to keep the client_secret safe.

> So, why was this extra step of sending a second request to obtain
>   access token added in the  specification?

Well, **Implicit** flow is less secure than **explicit** flow since access toke is send to the user agent. But there is an attribute expire in the case of implicit flow which will get expired unless you have specified **scope** as **no_expiry**. Also server side flow can be used only by the apps that are registerd

> It seems all the security of oAuth stems from ssl and the client's
>   ability to keep their client secret secret. Am I right in this
>   conclusion?

Again **client_secret** will be available in server side flow. But yes, client should take care that access_token is not given out

Check out this [link](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/02/more-on-oauth-implicit-flow-application.html). It gives an example of possible vulnerability in **ouath**.